# Omission of function declarations

Tags: c, compiler-construction, include

Are there any circumstances in which it is acceptable to omit function declarations from source files? I have a C project which will not compile, and I do not know why. As far as I can determine the compiler (GCC 4.4.1) cannot find the declaration of the 'sepData' typedef when it gets to the declaration of the function 'sysData' in 'system.h'.

From sepsis.h

```
typedef struct {
    int16 intensity;
    int16 offset;
} sepData;
```

From sepsis.c

```
sepData sepR, sepIR;
```

From system.h

```
void sysData(sepData *sepR, sepData *sepIR);
```

From system.c

```
#include "system.h"
#include "sepsis.h"

extern sepData sepR, sepIR;

void sysData(sepData *sepR, sepData *sepIR)
{
}
```

If I remove the declaration of 'sysData' from 'system.h', then the project compiles without error. Not knowing a great deal about C, I thought that including such declarations was compulsory. Is anyone able to explain what is going on here?

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? As a side note, do you really want to name the function arguments the same as the global variables?

Comment: In C89/90, prototypes are recommended, but neither a prototype nor a declaration is truly mandatory (at least according to the language spec -- any sane manager will require prototypes).

Comment: It looks like the more appropriate fix is to swap the order of the includes, so that `sepsis.h` is included before `system.h`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include "system.h"
#include "sepsis.h"
```

If `system.h` does not `#include "sepsis.h"` itself, then the type `sepData` will not be known when you prototype the `sysData()` function, and you get the error message. You can probably paper over this problem by swapping the order of the two headers:

```
#include "sepsis.h"
#include "system.h"
```

But that only fixes this specific compilation unit. If you have other compilation units in this application, you'll need to care about the order of `#include` lines, which gets tiresome. Perhaps `system.h` needs to `#include "sepsis.h"` itself -- and have `sepsis.h` guard against multiple inclusion via the usual incantation:

```
#ifndef _SEPSIS_H_
#define _SEPSIS_H_
...
#endif // _SEPSIS_H_
```

Your codebase was able to compile without the `sysData()` prototype because you hadn't *used* the function before the function's declaration. Had you used the function before declaration, I expect the compiler would have given you a *warning* message and assumed every single argument should be an `int` and the return type should also be an `int`. (The old K&R rules.) This would, of course, not work, but it might not be obvious *why* it doesn't work. (Yay C.)

Comment: I have previously tried swapping the order of the two includes as recommended, but got the same error, namely "system.h:67: error: expected ')' before '*' token". However, I was not aware of the fact that you can include a header file in another header - that seems to of solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

When you include `system.h`, you haven't yet declared the type `sepData`.

Switch around the order of includes and try again.

```
#include "sepsis.h"
#include "system.h"

extern sepData sepR, sepIR;

//you might also want to re-think your arguments' names
void sysData(sepData *_sepR, sepData *_sepIR)
{
}
```

Comment: The sepData function operates on the two global variables sepR and sepIR. I chose to explicitly pass them as arguments as it makes it clear (to me at least) which variables the function manipulates. Is this considered poor form?

Comment: @Zack It's best to avoid global variables as much as possible. But if you've got 'em, I personally think it's pointless, confusing, and inefficient to pass global variables as arguments to a function that *always* operates on those global variables.